# Find pdf of $Y=X*I$, where $I$ is a indicator function on $[a, b]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Find $pdf$ of $Y=X*I$, where $I$ is an indicator function on $[a, b]$(taking value$1$ if $a\le X\le b$ ans taking $0$ otherwise) and $X$ has a pdf $f_X(x)$

What I confused is that does $Y$ necessary a continues random variable? It seems that $P(Y=0)=1-[F_X(b)-F_X(a)]\ne 0$.

But the answer given by my teacher is a continues one.

Comment: $X\notin[a,b]\implies Y=0$ so that: $\Pr(Y=0)\geq\Pr(X\notin[a,b])$. So if the RHS is positive then $Y$ is not a continuous random variable. If the RHS is not positive then $Y=X$ a.s. so then $Y$ has the same PDF as $X$.

Comment: @drhab Brilliant proof! Thanks a lot.